# Redirect http to https and then redirect it to subdomain's folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

First case:

I tried to redirect http to https and following rule works well.

For example: **http://subdomain.domain.com** to **https://subdomain.domain.com**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Second Case:
I tried to redirect **http://subdomain.domain.com** to **http://subdomain.domain/folder**. For this I used this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

I want these redirection:

**http://subdomain.domain.com** to **https://subdomain.domain.com/folder**

and

**https://subdomain.domain.com** to **https://subdomain.domain.com/folder**

I tried merging the above rules but no luck.

One more thing, I am not using `.htaccess` ,instead I put these rules to 
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Actually there are two files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

1. default
2. default-ssl

I put the rule to redirect `http` to `https` as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

in `default` file and

put rule to  redirect to sub-domain's `folder` as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

in `default-ssl` file.